# Need help to identify smd component of VGA adapter MSI GTX1070

Tags: identification, surface-mount, vga

I did clean my VGA adapter MSI Geforce gtx 1070 with compressed air and one smd component has gone, now the adapter did not work. On another adapter I found out the marking on the component body and it is just - VT. I have no idea what is this. Could somebody help to find out what is this. On the PCB it is marked as U506.

[image]

[image]

Comment: "I did clean my VGA adapter MSI Geforce gtx 1070 with compressed air" Properly soldered components don't fall off if you blow some air on them. Are you absolutely sure this part was mounted to begin with? Looking at your 2nd pic that doesn't seem to be the case - the pads of U506 look clean, with solder paste from the assembly still there. If something had been soldered poorly there then fallen off, the pads would look way more messy. The pic is a bit low res though so I could be wrong.

Comment: For example different revisions of the same PCB could have removed some component from the material list since it was considered superfluous. So comparing two supposedly identical boards doesn't necessarily say much, unless you know for sure they are from the same batch.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a [74LVC1G80](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74LVC1G80.pdf) Single D-type flip-flop.
[image]
 <sub>From page 2 of the linked Nexperia datasheet</sub>

Not sure which package - it's either TSSOP5(SOT535-1) or SC-74A(SOT753).  You'll have to check the dimension of the package and/or pin pitch.
The TSSOP5 package is about 2mm wide with a pitch of 0.65mm while the SC-74A is about 3mm wide with a pitch of almost 1mm.